Using Custom Font - Tableau
I want to use my organization's custom font in our Tableau dashboards. The font is DM Sans. We have installed the font on the Tableau Server and the individual machines on which Tableau Desktop is used, and changed all fonts to DM Sans.
The font is loading on the Tableau Server and the machines on which it is installed, but on other machines it is rendering "Times New Roman" font.
The dashboard is also embedded in a webpage where the font being loaded is "Times New Roman".
Have a few questions around this,

How can I get the custom font to load on the client browser, even if they do not have the font installed on their OS?
Is it possible to have a single solution that will apply the custom font across Tableau Desktop, Tableau Server, Tableau Cloud, and client browser?


If i had a dollar for every time I heard this question I'd have like 8 dollars. Read this answer first for context and then read this question and answer for a shot at going about it. I've messed with it a ton, was never entirely fruitful.
